# iOS 5 json - go deeper into json string?

Tags: xcode, json, sdk, ios5

With iOS 5 u can use the native json support.
I tried a lot of things but i cant parse the following:
http://api.audioboo.fm/users/40956/audio_clips.json

My target is to get every audio_clip and also the id's and so on.

What i've tried for simple json strings is:

```
     NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1

                      options:kNilOptions 
                      error:&error];


     latestBoo = [json objectForKey:@"audio_clips"];
```

But with this complex json string i dont know how to get these informations.

Hope for an answer :)

Comment: A little clarification, that's not a "complex JSON string" but a "complex JSON object". You can prettify it using various online services to see it more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *parsedData = [NSJSONSerialization 
                  JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1

                  options:kNilOptions 
                  error:&error];

// Response Data is the JSON String...

NSLog(@"Parsed Data: %@", parsedData);

NSDictionary *bodyDictionary = [parsedData valueForKey:@"body"];

NSLog(@"bodyDictionary: %@", bodyDictionary);

NSArray *audioClipsArray = [bodyDictionary valueForKey:@"audio_clips"];

NSLog(@"Response array: %@", audioClipsArray);
```

In the audioClipsArray is now your array with all elements of audio clips.

Answer (score 0):

The root of your JSON contains a `body`, which in turns contains `audio_clips`. So you should do

```
NSArray *audioClips = [(NSDictionary *)[json objectForKey:@"body"] objectForKey:@"audio_clips"];
```

Then you can iterate over the `audioClips` array.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot provide you any iOS code, but therefore a java style pseudo code snippet to access these information:

```
// serialize string into json object
JSONObject json = serialize(responseData);


// request member "body" as json object
JSONObject body = json.getAsJsonObject("body");

// request member "audio_clips" as json array
JSONArray audio_clips = body.getAsJsonArray("audio_clips"); 

// iterate over json array
for(JSONObject audio_clip : audio_clips) {
     // access members of audio_clip, e.g. id
     int id = audio_clip.getInt("id");
}
```

hope this helps
-axel

Comment: if you want to analyze the structure of a JSON object I recommend to use a JSON editor... there are plenty available, a simple online tool is this one http://braincast.nl/samples/jsoneditor/

Comment: well, I know that these two languages are very different. but since it does not contain any java specific code fragments/library calls it could help to understand the way to deal with JSON objects - also any OO programmer should be able to read this kind of pseudo code